# Insert one row with same constant value in specific column (Rstudio)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df like following : 3 columns, 9 rows.

```
  device voltage current
1  north       1       1
2  north       2       2
3  north       3       3
4   west       1      10
5   west       2      20
6   west       3      30
7 center       1     100
8 center       2     200
9 center       3     300
```

How can I insert a constant **new current** value for each device group ? (for example new current value = 75)? this is what I would like to obtain **:**

```
   device voltage current
1   north       1       1
2   north       2       2
3   north       3       3
4   north      NA      75
5    west       1      10
6    west       2      20
7    west       3      30
8    west      NA      75
9  center      NA      75
10 center       1     100
11 center       2     200
12 center       3     300
```

I would like "voltage" variable to get NA value so that I will be able to use na.approx for future interpolation. 
Thanks a ton for your help.
I 've tried this (I 've seen it elsewhere) without success.

```
df %>% 
  split(.$current) %>% 
  map(~add_row(., device = (.$device), current = 75, votage = NA)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO! In the future, make your data more directly copy-paste'able. One way to solve your problem is to use `group_by` and `do` from `dplyr`. The solution looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  device = rep(c("north", "west", "center"), each = 3),
  voltage = rep(1:3, times = 3),
  current = c(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(device) %>% 
  do(add_row(., device = .$device[1], current = 75))
```

or alternatively if you prefer `purrr`:

```
df %>% 
  split(.$device) %>% 
  imap(~add_row(.x, device = .y, current = 75)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Which produces :

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   device [3]
   device voltage current
   <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
 1 center       1     100
 2 center       2     200
 3 center       3     300
 4 center      NA      75
 5 north        1       1
 6 north        2       2
 7 north        3       3
 8 north       NA      75
 9 west         1      10
10 west         2      20
11 west         3      30
12 west        NA      75
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

A solution using `full_join`, which takes care of the `NA` values in `voltage`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  device = rep(c("north", "west", "center"), each = 3),
  voltage = rep(1:3, times = 3),
  current = c(1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300)
)

# new dataframe, with one row for each value of device:
new_df <- df %>%
  select(device) %>%
  unique() %>%
  mutate(current = 75)

df %>%
  full_join(new_df)
```